# Issue on Targeting First Previous Closest Element with Class Name

Tags: javascript, jquery

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/f9t7njcm/)**

Can you please take a look at above Demo and let me know why I am not able to grab `.val()` of First Closest- Previous `.txtfilename` element.

Please try to click On **PDF** btn to see the result

```
 $(document).on("click", ".pdf-download", function(){
        var targetFileInput =  $(this).prev().closest(".txtfilename").val();
        alert(targetFileInput);
 });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="content hide">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="" name="txtfilename" type="text" placeholder="File Name" class="form-control input-md txtfilename" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:10px !important;">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" id="chart1png" data-chart="chart1" class="btn btn-default text-center png-download">PNG</button>
            <button type="button" id="chart1pdf" data-chart="chart1" class="btn btn-default text-center pdf-download">PDF</button>
            <button type="button" id="chart1jpg" data-chart="chart1" class="btn btn-default text-center jpg-download">JPG</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: *"Can you please take a look at above Demo..."* No, all relevant code belongs here on StackOverflow. You've asked 142 questions. You should know this by now.

Comment: Hi Barmar just want to not keep post messy, they were already in fiddle

Comment: @Suffii It's preferable to put everything relevant here.

Comment: We only need to see one DIV, since they're all the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have incorrect selector to target desired input element. use:

```
 $(document).on("click", ".pdf-download", function(){
    var targetFileInput =  $(this).closest('.form-group').prev().find(".txtfilename").val();
    alert(targetFileInput);
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vz7uc7hq/)**

You can also use:

```
$(this).closest('.content').find(".txtfilename").val();
```

**[Approach 2 demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7hsq6u30/)**

Comment: Thanks Milind but can you please let me know why we have to use the `.form-group` ?

Comment: @Suffii: that is because `closest('.form-group')` is sibling div of div having required input element in it.

Comment: great thanks, have to wait 10 min to accept the correct answer!

Comment: @Suffii If you don't go up to `.form-group` first, `.prev()` returns the `.png-download` button.